# College algebra Books

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, fractions, book-recommendation

I am looking for college algebra books containing as many elementary algebra questions as possible. For example, simplify

$$\frac{x}{1+x^2} - \frac{4}{(1+x^2)^2}, \quad \frac{4x}{1+2x+ x^3} - \frac{10x^2}{x^2+x^3},$$ 
or factorise 
$$x^4-2x^2+1, \quad 2x^2 + 4x+2, \quad etc.$$

It would be good if the book contains challenging  and non-routine questions.

Problems for my attempts:

1. Factorize the following polynomial on three factors (polynomials with degree is greater that 0) with integer coefficients.
   $$x^6+27$$
2. Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers such that $abc=1$. Prove that:
   $$\frac{1}{1+a+ab}+\frac{1}{1+b+bc}+\frac{1}{1+c+ca}=1.$$
3. Solve the following equation.
   $$\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt[3]{2-x}}=x.$$

Comment: I am ready to be a book for you. I'll post here three problems. If you'll solve at least one of them, so I'll post here more three problems. OK?

Comment: Sure. I am ready.

Comment: I posted. Good luck! If you solved something post the solution in this topic.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for your suggestions. I think your comments above are more suited to an answer.

Comment: It would be better to say algebra than pre-algebra in this context.

Comment: Until you get the right books or other sources, you see what [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E2%7D+-+%5Cfrac%7B4%7D%7B(1%2Bx%5E2)%5E2%7D) can do with questions like this.

Answer (score 3):

There are hundreds of 1800s algebra texts that have been digitized and are freely available on the internet (in the U.S. at least), and many of those would be useful for what you want. The following are some of the better known “advanced school level” algebra texts:

William Steadman Aldis, [**A Text Book of Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/atextbookalgebr00aldigoog/page/n7)

George Chrystal, [**Algebra. An Elementary Text-Book, Part I**](https://archive.org/details/algebraelementar01chryuoft/page/n6)

Henry Sinclair Hall and Samuel Ratcliffe Knight, [**Higher Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/higheralgebraas00kniggoog/page/n6)

Elias Loomis, [**A Treatise on Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonalge09loomgoog/page/n9)

Charles Smith, [**A Treatise on Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonalge00smitgoog/page/n8)

Isaac Todhunter, [**Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/algebraforuseco04todhgoog/page/n9)

You'll find that intermediate level and beginning level texts are more numerous, many of which are by the same authors as above as well as by other authors. Also, look for [older such books with "Key" in their titles](https://www.google.com/search?q=Key+to+algebra&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899) (see [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Key+to+algebra+archive.org) also), as these will be solution manuals to certain corresponding texts.

Below are two especially nice algebra texts at a lower level (than those above) that I happen to know about.

George Chrystal, [**Introduction to Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoal00chry/page/n1)

> This book, written about a decade after his better known 2-part **Algebra. An Elementary Text-Book**, is somewhat historically significant because of its advocation of graphical methods in algebra which, in large part due to this book, began being incorporated non-trivially into algebra textbooks beginning around 1900. (I suspect another reason for the introduction of graphical methods in algebra around this time is due to the introduction of graph paper for classroom use around the 1890s.)

Charles Davies, [**New Elementary Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/newelementaryal01davigoog/page/n4)